# Change the data shown on a powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an excel sheet that has the data, I have a powerpoint presentation that has a few charts. I need to run a report eveyday, so i am trying to automate it. I wrote a vba script to copy and paste the data from excel sheet to the chart in powerpoint . But i am unable to change the selection region(the data that is displayed on the graph eventhough there may be more data).
I have written the following script. Any help that helps me change the data to be displayed on the chart is appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r As Range
Dim powerpointapp As Object
Dim mypresentation As Object
Dim myslide As Object
Dim myshape As Object
Dim ppath As String
Dim titlesh As Object
Dim tdate As String
Dim chartsh As Object

tdate = Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
ppath = "path to ppt"
Set powerpointapp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Open(ppath)
Set myslide = mypresentation.Slides(1)
Set titlesh = myslide.Shapes("Dateh")
titlesh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tdate

Set myslide = mypresentation.Slides(2)
Set chartsh = myslide.Shapes("Chart 6")
chartsh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Clear
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Tracking").Range("B84:C158")
r.Copy
chartsh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B74").Value = r.Value



powerpointapp.Visible = True
powerpointapp.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what your data looks like. You may use .end or usedrange or a loop to looking for keyword in order to locate the end of data.
Some code just to demo the idea:

```
Dim lastline1 As Long, lastline2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Tracking")
lastline1 = ws.Cells(84, 2).End(xlDown).Row() 'Need to check whether row 84 is the last row, otherwise it may fly to 65536 or 1048576.
lastline2 = ws.UsedRange(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Row

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Tracking").Range("B84:C" & lastline2)
```